# When to use triggers in SQL for statement with conditional logic?

Tags: sql, triggers

I found this piece of code while learning. The purpose is to check if there is enough stock for the quantity ordered: if there is not, an error message will display, if there is, the ordered stock info will be logged into Orders table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER ConfirmStock 
ON Orders
INSTEAD OF Insert
AS 

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Products AS p
INNER JOIN inserted AS i on p.Product = i.Product
WHERE p.Quantity < i.Quantity 
RAISERROR ('You cannot  place order when there is no product stock',16,1);

ELSE
INSERT INTO dbo.Orders(Customer, Product, Quantity, OrderUpdate, TotalAmount)
SELECT Customer, Product, Quantity, OrderUpdate, TotalAmount from inserted;
```

My question is: Why is there a need for a trigger for this code? Shouldn't the "IF EXISTS..." statement alone help to achieve the same purpose?

Thank you.

Comment: When leaning they will suggest or show something like this is possible. in programing there will be so many right solutions for a single question. we need too use our judgement  .

Comment: A trigger will always execute, there's no way someone - unintentionally or intentionally - can avoid it, as they can do with "IF EXISTS..." statements.